# Сделать синонимами метки [случайные-числа] и [рандом]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [случайные-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) (682 вопроса, есть описание)
- [рандом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc) (17 вопросов, нет описания).

Предлагаю сделать их синонимами. Основная метка - [случайные-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0): с неё больше вопросов, есть описание, а у метки [рандом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc) название какое-то разговорное.

Вручную заменять одну метку на другую мне кажется неэффективным, так как 17 вопросов - не так уж мало, да и тогда метку можно будет создать снова.

Comment: еще можно было заметить, что в [tag:случайные-числа] уже есть синоним для [tag:random]

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ещё бы [tag:генерация-случайных-данных] туда же...

Comment: @wchistow генерация случайных данных и чисел — разные понятия.

Comment: @Зонтик, интересно, что в описании метки написано исключительно про случайные *числа*. ;)

Comment: @wchistow потому что описание неправильное ([предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/876228) новое). В некоторых вопросах идёт речь не про генерацию случайных чисел, а именно других случайных данных (видео, строк, объектов и). А с вопросов про случайные числа эту метку надо убрать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

готово!

```
updating post history, 18 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 17 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 15 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'рандом': [рандом] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 697
tag remapping of [случайные-числа] and [рандом] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym рандом -> случайные-числа was approved!
```